# Transform Correlation Matrix into dataframe with records for each row column pair

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have a large matrix of correlations (1093 x 1093).  I'm trying my matrix into a dataframe that has a column for every row and column pair, so it would (1093)^2 records.

Here's a snippet of my matrix

```
            60516        45264        02117
60516  1.00000000 -0.370793012 -0.082897941
45264 -0.37079301  1.000000000  0.005145601
02117 -0.08289794  0.005145601  1.000000000
```

The goal from here would be to have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
row column correlation
60516 60516 1.000000000
60516 45264 -0.370793012
```

........ and so on.

Anyone have any tips?  Let me know if I can clarify anything

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I'm assuming you plan to use it as an input to something else. If so, can we have the full problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For matrix `m`, you could do:

```
data.frame(row=rownames(m)[row(m)], col=colnames(m)[col(m)], corr=c(m))

#     row   col         corr
# 1 60516 60516  1.000000000
# 2 45264 60516 -0.370793010
# 3 02117 60516 -0.082897940
# 4 60516 45264 -0.370793012
# 5 45264 45264  1.000000000
# 6 02117 45264  0.005145601
# 7 60516 02117 -0.082897941
# 8 45264 02117  0.005145601
# 9 02117 02117  1.000000000
```

But if your matrix is symmetrical and if you are not interested in the diagonal, then you can simplify it to:

```
data.frame(row=rownames(m)[row(m)[upper.tri(m)]], 
           col=colnames(m)[col(m)[upper.tri(m)]], 
           corr=m[upper.tri(m)])

#     row   col         corr
# 1 60516 45264 -0.370793012
# 2 60516 02117 -0.082897941
# 3 45264 02117  0.005145601
```

Comment: Hi @jbaums. Let's say my matrix is not symmetric. How could I get rid of the like pairs in the data frame or redundent pairs in the data frame. i.e. get rid of pairs `(x, x)` for all x and pairs `(y, x)` for those in which the pair `(x, y)` has already been recorded. Any advice? In other words, I want the data on the upper triangle (not including diagonal) without making the assumption of a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 4):

With a bit of tidyverse is easy:

given a correlation matrix `X`:

```
X %>% as.data.frame %>% tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-rowname)
```

You can, of course, change the names using `rownames_to_column` and `pivot_longer` arguments, and can also add `filter(rowname != name)` to remove the diagonal correlations.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. Given a correlation matrix `Acor`:

You can create the data.frame as:

```
UpperT <- Acor[upper.tri(Acor, diag = TRUE)]
n <- dim(Acor)[[1]]
Row <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(n), FUN = seq_len))
Column <- rep(seq_len(n), seq_len(n))
Df <- data.frame(UpperT, Row, Column)
```

For example, with correlation matrix:

```
set.seed(24)
A <- matrix(rnorm(25, 5, 2), ncol = 5)
Acor <- cor(A)

> Acor
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,]  1.0000000  0.3398424  0.8876580  0.2582569 -0.5699901
[2,]  0.3398424  1.0000000  0.5897580 -0.7416699  0.2502752
[3,]  0.8876580  0.5897580  1.0000000 -0.1631381 -0.2101108
[4,]  0.2582569 -0.7416699 -0.1631381  1.0000000 -0.8067492
[5,] -0.5699901  0.2502752 -0.2101108 -0.8067492  1.0000000
```

You get:

```
> Df
       UpperT Row Column
1   1.0000000   1      1
2   0.3398424   1      2
3   1.0000000   2      2
4   0.8876580   1      3
5   0.5897580   2      3
6   1.0000000   3      3
7   0.2582569   1      4
8  -0.7416699   2      4
9  -0.1631381   3      4
10  1.0000000   4      4
11 -0.5699901   1      5
12  0.2502752   2      5
13 -0.2101108   3      5
14 -0.8067492   4      5
15  1.0000000   5      5
```