# How to make a 4 columns dataframe from a correlation matrix, including the variables, the upper and lower triangle, without the diagonal itself?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, correlation

I have a correlation matrix of 1988 rows × 1988 columns

I can make a 3 columns dataframe with the upper  triangle without the diagonal itself and without self comparisons, using  np.triu:

`df_upper = df.where(pd.np.triu(pd.np.ones(df.shape), k=1).astype(bool)).stack().reset_index()`

df_upper is 1975078 rows × 3 columns (below you see the fisrt rows)

| Var1 | Var2 | p-val* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 59 | 66 | 0.662 |
| 59 | 301 | 0.5187 |
| 59 | 529 | 0.5957 |

I tried to get the lower triangle with:

`df_lower = df.where(pd.np.tril(pd.np.ones(df.shape), k=1).astype(bool)).stack().reset_index()`

But the result included the diagonal and also repeated comparisons: Var1 - Var2 and Var2 - Var1,
so  df_lower had much more rows: 1979053 rows × 3 columns

I need a 4 columns dataframe (1975078 rows × 4 columns) with the following columns as the example below with a few rows:

| Var1 | Var2 | p-val | p-val* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 59 | 66 | 0.662 | 0.997 |
| 59 | 301 | 0.5187 | 0.6773 |
| 59 | 529 | 0.5957 | 0.7874 |

Where columns p-val shows values from the lower triangle and p-val* shows values from the upper triangle.

To do so the values of p-val and p-val* (3rd and 4th columns) have to meet the order of Var1-Var2 (first and second column), and the dataframe shall not include the diagonal itself nor self comparisons.

I have no idea how to achieve this, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is your correlation matrix symmetric? (across the diagonal?)

Comment: Yes, it is @DAdams

Comment: Then you don't need information from the bottom half of the matrix? 
 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Also just noticing: your lower has a ```df.where``` and your upper does not.

Comment: @DAdams the upper triangle values are adjusted p-values and the lower triangle non-adjusted p-values. I meant the dataframe is symmetric because both triangles have the same pairwise comparisons.

Comment: @DAdams I edited the code for df_upper, both have df.where

Comment: Hi @jbaums I found a previous  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28035166/5033924)  where the solution you posted is quite the solution I need. Do you know how can I make the dataframe I need as explained in my question?